# exclude documents from query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Working with MongoDB + NodeJS. Basic question. I have the following code that doesn't work. I.e. it excludes all documents from the search, and I only want to exclude 'test' documents.

```
meetingSchema.find({
'name.displayValue': {'$text' : {'$search' : '-test'} }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this & use not equal to :

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/

```
meetingSchema.find({
'name.displayValue': { $ne: "test" }
})
```

Comment: I used $nin earlier. Which would make it so that meetings titled 'test meeting' and not just 'test' are excluded?

Comment: I don't like using regex to exclude things... it seems clunky